# What `find` command deletes everything in a directory except for CVS folders?

Tags: bash, find, cvs

I have a dir:

```
$ tree
.
|-- CVS
|   |-- Entries
|   |-- Entries.Log
|   |-- Repository
|   `-- Root
|-- dirA
|   |-- CVS
|   |   |-- Entries
|   |   |-- Repository
|   |   `-- Root
|   |-- file1
|   `-- file2
|-- dirB
|   |-- CVS
|   |   |-- Entries
|   |   |-- Repository
|   |   `-- Root
|   |-- file3
|   `-- file4
|-- file5
`-- file6
```

I can find all files I want to delete with this command:

```
$ find . -name CVS -prune -o -type f -print
```

But if I change `-print` to `-delete`

```
$ find . -name CVS -prune -o -type f -delete
```

Everything is gone. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the man pages for `find`, under `-delete`:

> When testing a find command line that you later intend to use with -delete, you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid later surprises. Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.

You can most probably just use `-exec rm {} +` instead of `-delete` in this context to do what you want, but as always when playing with fire: make *very* sure that it works before going in hard.